# Security issue with outsourcing work

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

**TLDR** *I allowed a chap from another country access to my PEM file on a separate project.*

Upon finishing my cloud practitioner cert I decided to upload a business website with my email central on the page for more information.

This website was up running and I did maintenance for over 10 months no problem. On a separate project, I gave my PEM file away to a random guy who I agreed to exchange the source code for said project. The PEM file was used to initiate a shell connection in order to connect to github.

Now my site is down and (maybe for a separate reason) I can't access AWS.

I still have the PEM file and my IP for the VM I spun up. Is there anyway to shut down the VM and avoid charges if this guy tries something?

PS. I understand the situation and that it may sound like I am said "guy" with "malicious" intentions. Truthfully I just want my future employers to know I can manage security and access management despite this hiccup via hosting a webpage for more than **insert minimum**.

Also accepting help to restart this process etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I assume you have some proof you're the one who rents the AWS. I'd suggest contacting AWS support immediately - they actually _can_ do something about this.

Comment: PEM files are a certificate storage container, so there are lots of ways you can use them. in what way was your system using the PEM in question? when you reference a certificate in relation to a website, I'm thinking you are using it for HTTPS, but that would have no impact on your access to AWS or anything else. tell us how you configured your system to use this certificate pair.

Comment: yea I used the pem file to initiate a shell connection in order to connect to github

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. Better way is [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1769592/edit) the question to provide additional info, clarifications etc. This keeps everything relevant readily available for the others. This for the future - I added it for you now.

Comment: then that should not impact your access to AWS. I recommend you first work with AWS support to get into your account there. at that point you can begin to troubleshoot the current version of the site, and your connection from github for your sites CI/CD or whatever. it sounds like the 3rd party only had access to the github account. if you have difficulties accessing your github account, work with their support to address them.